# How to just copy assets from entry directory to output directory with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, build, filesystems

say my entry is this:

```
counters
   block.json
   counters.css
   counters.php
   counters.js
```

I'd like to only process counters.js, and just copy all the other files to the output directory. How to with webpack? Which tool?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out this (just copying only the relevant code):

```
  entry: {
    counters: ['./blocks/counters/counters.js', './blocks/counters/block.json', './blocks/counters/counters.css', './blocks/counters/counters.php'],
  },
```

Then:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json|\.css|\.php/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: '../[path]/[name][ext]'
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            plugins: ['lodash'],
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            cacheDirectory: true
          }
        }
      }, // babel
    ] // rules
  }, // module
```

This will copy all the files from /blocks/counters to /build/blocks/counters, compiling counters.js and leaving as-is the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CopyWebpackPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/)

Example:

```
plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, './counters/filename'),
      to: path.resolve(__dirname, './output')
    }
  ])
],
```